# scribd_fu gsub error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gsub, scribd

I have an application which allow user upload documents to Scribd. I tried to use scribd_fu in Rails. An error occurred when the controller try to save the model.

```
NoMethodError in DocumentsController#processupload

private method `gsub' called for nil:NilClass
```

here is the related controller

```
def processupload

@document = Document.new(params[:document])
if @document.save
  session[:scribdid] = @document.ipaper_access_key
else
    xxxxx
```

and this is the related html form

```
<form action="/documents/processupload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="FqTCmlGGIvRjiaiaa+YtF50wgI7FfpxfrZsulLCbXcw=" />
<label class="label_h2">Upload a Document</label>
<input id="document_document_upload" name="document[document_upload]" size="30" type="file" /></div> 
<div class="buttons"><button type="submit" class="positive"><img src="/images/icons/tick.png" alt="Save Document"/>Save Document</button>
</form>
```

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: will you please paste your Document model code.

Comment: class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_ipaper_and_uses 'Paperclip'
end


that's all, if I comment out that line, everything will be fine....

Comment: Can you post the exception trace?  Something in the scribd_fu gem should be throwing an error, so locating that line is going to tell you a lot about what you're missing.

Comment: these are the trace related to scribd_fu

/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/scribd_fu-2.0.6/lib/scribd_fu/paperclip.rb:40:in `prefix'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/scribd_fu-2.0.6/lib/scribd_fu/paperclip.rb:15:in `get_content_type'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/scribd_fu-2.0.6/lib/scribd_fu.rb:189:in `scribdable?'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/scribd_fu-2.0.6/lib/scribd_fu.rb:184:in `upload_to_scribd'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd ensure the mimetype of the document you're trying to upload is supported by ScribdFu. That's usually the biggest cause of an error. (I wrote ScribdFu :))

Comment: Hi Matt,

Thanks for the answer. But I am uploading a PDF file, which should be supported by scribd. Is there any other method for tracing the error?

Comment: thanks matt. matt help me found the problem finally, i missed the paperclip setting of database. http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip